# How to have HTTPS on Github page with custom domain

Tags: security, github, https, github-pages

I stumbled across this page and wonder how to have HTTPS with custom domain on a github page

https://github.com/2factorauth/twofactorauth

https://twofactorauth.org/

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of solutions centered around using a free CloudFlare account.

Here's a link to some instructions: https://blog.cloudflare.com/secure-and-fast-github-pages-with-cloudflare/

Answer (score 0):

Note (2 years later): since May 2018, GitHub Pages themselves will be accessed through https directly (no need for a custom domain just for TLS access)

See "[Custom domains on GitHub Pages gain support for HTTPS](https://blog.github.com/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/)"

> [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) is the best way to quickly publish beautiful websites for you and your projects. Just edit, push, and your changes are live.
>   GitHub Pages [has supported custom domains since 2009](https://blog.github.com/2009-01-21-cname-support-for-github-pages/), and sites on the `*.github.io` domain [have supported HTTPS since 2016](https://blog.github.com/2016-06-08-https-for-github-pages/).
>   **Today, custom domains on GitHub Pages are gaining support for HTTPS as well, meaning over a million GitHub Pages sites will be served over HTTPS**.

[image: https://blog.github.com/assets/img/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-lock.png]

> We have partnered with the certificate authority [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) on this project. As supporters of Let’s Encrypt’s mission to make the web more secure for everyone, we’ve officially become Silver-level sponsors of the initiative